# Detach / remove boot VHD from SSD

Tags: boot, ssd, windows-11, vhd

My laptop has a single SSD with partitions as shown in attached photo. As I messed something up with BIOS password, I couldn't access BIOS to change the boot order. When I installed Windows 11 (Home), I had to removed my SSD, plugged it into a USB adapter and used Win-to-USB tool to make a bootable disk. I then inserted the SSD back and installed Windows 11 when the laptop first booted from the SSD.
After installation, there is a VHD formed in the same SSD. I researched and guessed that the VHD helps to make OS boot faster. However, there are some issues such as all downloads are automatically stored in the VHD that reduces the storage quickly (I could manually remove the downloads to the `D:` drive but still), a few days ago latest Win 11 experience pack was not able to be installed for some reason related to this VHD, and I could not enable Hibernate function because of the VHD that drains the battery quite fast in Sleep mode.

So my first solution was trying to detach / remove this VHD in the hope that converted the boot to the physical SSD and just boot from there. But I couldn't find any info to indicate if it is safe or feasible to do so.
Otherwise is there any solution such that I can just change the boot to the physical SSD and able to fix all the issues above? Many thanks.

SSD partitions:

[image: SSD partitions]

Comment: You did some things I would not do to install Windows 11. I think it may be best for you to back up what you can and install Windows 11 properly (one disk only during the install, and use the standard Windows 11 ISO to install).

Comment: Thanks, the problem as I mentioned was I messed up the BIOS password and now unable to correctly enter BIOS password to allow boot from USB drive. I thought of another solution that was to insert my SSD into another a laptop that could be booted by USB drive and install the OS from there. But there are also some worries of mismatched info of bios, CPU, motherboard etc. when I insert my SSD back to the current laptop.

Comment: If you messed up the BIOS password, you may not be able to proceed unless you can remember it

Comment: My head hurts reading this. None of it makes any sense. Just wipe everything and start over.

Answer (score 1):

I read all the information carefully

You did some things I would not do to install Windows 11.

I think it may be best for you to back up what you can and install Windows 11 properly (one disk only during the install, and use the standard Windows 11 ISO to install).

At this point, there is little else you can do.

A proper Windows 11 Install will create the correct partitions and be reliable.